# Parse XML in PHP by specific attribute

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I need to get `<name>` and `<URL>` tag's value where `subtype="mytype"`.How can do it in PHP?
I want document name and test.pdf path in my result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <test>
        <required>
            <item type="binary">
                <name>The name</name>
            <url visibility="restricted">c:/temp/test/widget.exe</url>
            </item>
            <item type="document" subtype="mytype">
                <name>document name</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">c:/temp/test.pdf</url>
            </item>
        </required>
    </test>
```

Comment: Is the <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php">XML Parser</a> extension an option?

Comment: I'm not sure who marked you down - or why - but Phil is absolutely correct.  SimpleXML (using XPath) is the way to go:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: @paulsm4: the downvote came from me. The reason was: no research effort shown, no code provided and the answer could be found by google or the SO search function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleXML and XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), eg

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/file.xml');

$items = $xml->xpath('//item[@subtype="mytype"]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $name = (string) $item->name;
    $url = (string) $item->url;
}
```

Comment: @dayana I assumed your XML was in a string variable. I've updated my answer to use a file

Comment: @dayana Feel free to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). While you're at it, accept some answers for your other questions

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.1.2+ has an extension called [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) enabled by default. It's very useful for parsing well-formed XML like your example above.

First, create a [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) instance, passing the XML to its constructor. SimpleXML will parse the XML for you. (This is where I feel the elegance of SimpleXML lies - SimpleXMLElement is the entire library's sole class.)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXml);
```

Now, you can easily traverse the XML as if it were any PHP object. Attributes are accessible as array values. Since you're looking for tags with specific attribute values, we can write a simple loop to go through the XML:

```
<?php
$yourXml = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <test>
        <required>
            <item type="binary">
                <name>The name</name>
            <url visibility="restricted">c:/temp/test/widget.exe</url>
            </item>
            <item type="document" subtype="mytype">
                <name>document name</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">c:/temp/test.pdf</url>
            </item>
        </required>
    </test>
END;

// Create the SimpleXMLElement
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXml);

// Store an array of results, matching names to URLs.
$results = array();

// Loop through all of the tests
foreach ($xml->required[0]->item as $item) {
    if ( ! isset($item['subtype']) || $item['subtype'] != 'mytype') {
        // Skip this one.
        continue;
    }

    // Cast, because all of the stuff in the SimpleXMLElement is a SimpleXMLElement.
    $results[(string)$item->name] = (string)$item->url;
}

print_r($results);
```

Tested to be correct in [codepad](http://codepad.org/DBJY2wer).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML Parser or SimpleXML.