# Parse XML in PHP which return multiple values

Tags: php, xml

I need to get "name" tag's value where tag is "required" and "optional".How can do it in PHP? 
I want result like:
required - binary name, doc test name
optional - doc name1, doc name2, doc name3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <required>
        <item type="binary">
            <name>binary name</name>
            <url visibility="restricted">test.exe</url>
        </item>
        <item type="document" subtype="mytype">
            <name>doc test name</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">my.pdf</url>
        </item>
    </required>
    <optional>
        <item type="document">
            <name>doc name1</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide1.pdf</url>
        </item>
        <item type="document2">
            <name>doc name2</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide2.pdf</url>
        </item>

        <item type="document3">
            <name>doc name3</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide3.pdf</url>
        </item>
    </optional>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <url>test4.xml</url>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</test>
```

Comment: did @Phil's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831194/parse-xml-in-php-by-specific-attribute/7831212#7831212) regarding SimpleXML/XPath work in that other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831194/parse-xml-in-php-by-specific-attribute)? how is this all that different from that question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML Parser or SimpleXML.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML with XPath: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

```
$xmlSrc =<<<XML
<test>
    <required>
        <item type="binary">
            <name>binary name</name>
            <url visibility="restricted">test.exe</url>
        </item>
        <item type="document" subtype="mytype">
            <name>doc test name</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">my.pdf</url>
        </item>
    </required>
    <optional>
        <item type="document">
            <name>doc name1</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide1.pdf</url>
        </item>
        <item type="document2">
            <name>doc name2</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide2.pdf</url>
        </item>

        <item type="document3">
            <name>doc name3</name>
            <url visiblity="visible">user_guide3.pdf</url>
        </item>
    </optional>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <url>test4.xml</url>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</test>
XML;


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlSrc);

$required_names = $xml->xpath('/test/required/item/name');
$optional_names = $xml->xpath('/test/optional/item/name');


print_r($required_names);
print_r($optional_names);
```

Comment: I replace $xml = simplexml_load_file('text.xml'); on place of $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlSrc); then its working fine for me.